# Why we use preposition while a verb has own meaning?

Tags: prepositions

I want to know about usage of preposition in sentence where a verb has own meaning but we put preposition why?
Pleas answer me briefly

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean. As it stands now, the question does not make any sense—what are you talking about?

Comment: Phrasal verbs perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I think phrasal verbs. Are phrasal verbs treated well in ELL? Cause the structure of the question makes it clear there are other issues as well.

Answer (score 2):

Because some verbs come from North-European languages, not Latin. They don't bear the full meaning in them.

You can climb a ladder ... up or down.

This is especially marked in German : you can't translate a sentence before having the post-position, which comes last.

"Wenn mein Nachbar das Klavier spielt, ich mache mein Fenster .. zu ? .. auf ?" ; when your neighbour plays the piano, you don't know until the last word, a post-position, if you are opening or closing your windows.

Comment: Super cool example.

Comment: Should be _mache ich_, surely?